# Help understanding proof of Euler's Homogeneous function theorem when t=1

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation

In the proof of Euler's homogeneous function theorem [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html)

The start with the definition of a homogeneous function
$$
f(tx,ty)=t^n f(x,y)
$$
and take the derivative of both sides w.r.t $t$ which gives

$$
nt^{n-1}f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial tx} \frac{\partial tx}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial ty} \frac{\partial ty}{\partial t} 
$$

or, letting letting $y'=ty$ and $x'=tx$ we can write this as

$$
nt^{n-1}f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x'} \frac{\partial x'}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \frac{\partial y'}{\partial t} 
$$

My questions are:

> How should I interpret $\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx}$. For example, if $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ what would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx}$?
>
> - also, Is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx}$ evaluated at $t=1$ different than $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$? If so, why?

Comment: It's simple: There is no ${\partial f\over\partial\,tx}$.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter So they are just using poor notation, and instead of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx}$ it would be better to use $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you problem resides in understanding the chain rule of differentiation. Suppose that you have a differentiable function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x,y)$ and that you have two
diferentiable functions $t\mapsto \phi(t)$ and $t\mapsto\psi(t)$,then what is the derivative
of $g:t\mapsto f(\phi(t),\psi(t))$?
The chain rule states that
$$
g'(t)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(\phi(t),\psi(t))\phi'(t)+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(\phi(t),\psi(t))\psi'(t).
$$
Now, we consider a particular case: We **fix** $(x,y)$ and we consider
$\phi:t\mapsto \phi(t)=tx$ and $\psi:t\mapsto \psi(t)=ty$, it follows that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\left(f(tx,ty)\right)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx,ty)x+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(tx,ty)y.
$$
But since $f(tx,ty)=t^nf(x,y)$, then from the above we conclude that
$$
nt^{n-1}f(x,y)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(tx,ty)x+
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(tx,ty)y.
$$
The final step is to choose $t=1$ and we are done.

Comment: But where I am confused is why (in your second to last line --  the equation above "the final step"), you have $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ -- notation that I agree with -- whereas the website I linked too has $\frac{\partial f}{\partial tx}$ . The former would seem to suggest that $t$ is held fixed and $x$ may change while the latter seems to me like we are holding $tx$ fixed when we take the derivative

Comment: I think the website you are referring to is not very serious, the symbol $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ means the derivative of $f$ with respect to first variable while the second is held fixed. While $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t x}$ means nothing!.

Answer (score 0):

Since we then have $$f(tx,ty)=(tx)^2+(ty)^2,$$ then $$\partial f_{tx}=2tx.$$ If $t=1,$ this becomes $$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2,$$ and $$\partial f_{x}=2x.$$